# Jquery animated popup box will not show

Tags: jquery, html, popup, popupwindow

I am trying to create a J-query animated popup box but when I run the site it shows just the Div.
this is my jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: true,
  show: {
    effect: "bounce",
    duration: 1000
  },
  hide: {
    effect: "explode",
    duration: 1000
  }
});
```

I want it to open when you launch the page but it just shows the text :(

Comment: you must include JQUery UI CSS & Js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are using jQueryUI method called dialog.

It is necessary to include jQuery and jQueryUI both and reference to jQuery should be included above/before jQueryUI.

Have a look on Reason 4:

> If you are using jQuery UI library then please ensure that order is
>   correct. You first need to include reference of jQuery library and
>   after that jQuery UI library.

at link:
http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2013/01/jquery-is-not-defined-error-reasons.html

Comment: I saw your code on jsfiddle and found that you need to give reference of jQuery first and then to jQueryUI like below: 

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

Include Jquery Css & JS in head section

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Your code is wrong try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      show: {
        effect: "bounce",
        duration: 1000
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 1000
      }
    });
    });
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fUgaf/6/)

Comment: i have done but it still wont work. i used dotluv theme heres my code:

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqueryUI/css/dot-luv/dot-luv.css">

Comment: it was a little confusing so i pasted all of the css from the file into the css bit